# Nested list element at position specified by a list

Tags: list-manipulation

I'm trying to avoid constructions like `Y[[X[[1]], X[[2]], X[[3]]]]`.

That is we have a nested list (`Y`) of depth $n$ and another list of depth 1 and length $n$ (`X`). We want to access the element of `Y` whose indexes coordinates are exactly the elements of X. What is the most reasonable way here?

Comment: Does Extract[y,x] work?

Comment: Wow, apparently it does, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, you can try:

```
Extract[y,x]
```

or

```
y[[Sequence @@ x]]
```

Comment: Yep, both of them work!

Comment: also `y[[##]] & @@ x`